Usage of word interception noun / verb and other grammatical way over the simple English
Assume I am penalised in one among the men or a lady where I stand before the counsel and I am not at all a guilty person. I must justify with my simple English, where even political influenced persons bombarding / leading the overall conversation(s). Political means like the one Facebook CEO who'd answered to the UK Counsel of Members once politely with all due respect - SO, together the reforming of Meta now as a platform in our world's trunk I can say, happening
Wherein presume like I am a sort of the person feel guilt just for simple emotional deviation by character wise. But very strong like a person who comes as a hero in the movie - from IMDB base
How best I can use the word - interception noun / verb and with other grammatical way over the simple English.
I am IT professional I know how this interceptor works as design pattern in C#.net / Java, even I feel it complex because I see Kotlin to Scala other than the one where it plays trivial vital role. See I am saying about myself, but the question is open.
I hope I make myself a clear question. This is what I read - gully by suspicion when it is broadcasted, but now I read a different title all together in / from IMDB base
So the anticipation is general and it is open to realm of English and it's grammar.

Your question is not clear. Please rewrite your question. Please write an example sentence using the word "interception". I don't understand what you write about facebook. I don't understand what you mean about answering political questions with simple English. I don't understand why you mention a movie called "Guilt by Suspicion". I don't understand how this connects to the word "interception".

I don't understand your first sentence either.

Assume I am penalised in one among the men or a lady= Not English. You might want to practice sentences using: Subject Verb Predicate.

@JamesK : I agree that the question could be misunderstood. It is concerning the various ways in which the word intercept - verb, noun, adjective is used. He finds no connection between the usage. (Google and Facebook can be legally intercepted, says UK spy boss ) - bbc.com/news/technology-2788763

@JamesMathai You may be correct, but you are reading a lot into the question that simply isn't in the text that the OP has written, and ignoring a lot of what he did write.

+1 OP should clarify the doubts raised by others. This way he would be able to get more answers.

@all - I am not a native English men. In my country India all languages are complicated and one speaks many language together been considered when the other party / parties not understood and as they give them and take a lead, so at one side either it is a beneficial or it's a lost by like with commodity, this how my country runs the whole business, when I say whole it's just a whole. OUT, of it,- English also the one although it is not an our language

Intercept evidence - justice and Interception attack.
According to my interpretation, the OP is primarily concerned with the verb "intercept" and its noun and adjective forms. After seeing the movie Guilty by Suspicion", he learned there is no link with the word "interceptor" used in the technology area.
Verb "intercept"  meaning.
This meaning is of interest to the OP in the given scenario.

Ref. Cambridge dictionary
to stop things, people, etc. as they go to a particular place:
to intercept calls/communications/emails

Intercept evidence - justice:.
The OP referred to the film Guilty by Suspicion. The website provides more information about whether intercept evidence is admissible in court.

Ref. justice .org.uk.
Intercept evidence' is the use of recordings or transcripts from intercepted communications as evidence in criminal or civil proceedings.
https://justice.org.uk/intercept-evidence/#:~:text='Intercept%20evidence'%20is%20the%20use,in%20criminal%20or%20civil%20proceedings.

Interception attack.
The web page explains how intercept evidence is acquired. The webpage must be viewed to see instances of Interception attacks.

Interception attack definition.
Interception attacks are any situation where a hacker intercepts and changes communication between two parties without their knowledge. To do that, the attacker may place themselves between the sender and the receiver — this is called a man-in-the-middle attack.
Other interception attack methods include:
Taking over wireless communication.
Manipulating network traffic.
Exploiting vulnerabilities in communication protocols.
Hacking network infrastructure.
Whatever the method, the goal is to eavesdrop, manipulate, or even impersonate the communication..
https://nordvpn.com/cybersecurity/glossary/interception-attacks/#:~:text=Interception%20attacks%20are%20any%20situation,in%2Dthe%2Dmiddle%20attack.

Interceptors in Technology.

Interceptors are used in conjunction with Java EE managed classes to allow developers to invoke interceptor methods on an associated target class, in conjunction with method invocations or lifecycle events. Common uses of interceptors are logging, auditing, and profiling.

Finally, I would suggest to the OP that it is difficult to discover correlations between words in technical jargon and other fields.
